# "<ExtendsNode: extends "base.html"> must be the first tag in the template." error in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I'm using:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

I get the following error:

> <ExtendsNode: extends "base.html"> must be the first tag in the template.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be the very first django template tag in your template.

Documentation says:

> If you use {% extends %} in a
>   template, it must be the first
>   template tag in that template.
>   Template inheritance won't work,
>   otherwise.

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)

Answer (score 6):

place `{% extends "base.html" %}` in line 1 of your editor. Literally put it in line 1. REMOVE all comments at the top if you have any..

Answer (score 0):

I also got into that problem.
I was using comment as the first tag it wasn't working.After I removed that it worked.
Used this:
{% comment %} inheriting the base html {% endcomment %}

To describe what I was doing.Got error.
Removed this and used extend as the first template tag.Worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to mention the `{% extends '<TEMPLATE_NAME>' %}` in the first line itself, don't even try to put comments on the first line.
This will surely resolve the error!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> <ExtendsNode: extends "base.html"> must be the first tag in the template.

Because I used [{% extends %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-extends) after [{% comment %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% comment %} <h1>Hello World</h1> {% endcomment %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

So, I used `{% extends %}` before `{% comment %}` as shown below, then the same error was solved:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% comment %} <h1>Hello World</h1> {% endcomment %}
```

`{% extends %}` is explained in [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) as shown below:

- If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

In addition, you can use `{% extends %}` after [{# #}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#comments) which is a single line comment and html tags without any error as shown below. *`{# #}` is not a tag but is a comment syntax in Django Templates:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{# This is a single line comment #}
<h1>Hello World</h1>
{% extends "base.html" %}
```